# Akka Streams - How to produce the size of a List followed by the entire List

Tags: akka-stream

I would like to consume a list of elements and then forward the size of the list followed by the full list of elements.

E.g.

```
Given List (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
When the source is fully consumed
Then the next processing-stage receives the elements List(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This is a toy problem I am attempting to solve; I appreciate that it's  bad practice to fully consuming the list before the next processing stage receives its first element.

I have the code that will calculate the size of the list.

```
val length: RunnableGraph[Future[Int]] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("myList.txt")).toMat(Sink.fold(0) {
    case (length, s) => length + s.length
})(Keep.right)
```

I'm not sure how to fully consume the list before sending the list to the next processing stage (preceded by the size of the list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`fold`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#fold[T](zero:T)(f:(T,Out)=%3ET):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) to accumulate both the size of the `List` and the `List` elements themselves, then use [`flatMapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#flatMapConcat[T,M](f:Out=%3Eakka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[T],M]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) and [`concat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#concat[U%3E:Out,Mat2](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[U],Mat2]):FlowOps.this.Repr[U]):

```scala
val data = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Source(data)
  .fold((0, List.empty[Int]))((acc, curr) => (acc._1 + 1, acc._2 :+ curr))
  .flatMapConcat {
    case (size, elems) => Source.single(size).concat(Source(elems))
  }
  .runForeach(println)
```

The above code prints:

```scala
5 // size of the list
1
2
3
4
5
```

Note that while the above code works in this toy example, it's not "streamlike" because it copies the entire `List` into memory (which negates the whole point of using streams). Hopefully this example serves to illustrate a few pieces of Akka Stream functionality, but don't follow this approach in production code.

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for - Thank you!